# "@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong." console message with flask-vite and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, vite

I wanted to use flask-vite to add some React components to my app.

I started by using the flask-vite Flask plugin to add Vite to my Flask project.

Then I installed React and carefully updated the configuration files, using a freshly created React project that I made with Vite as a reference.

I couldn't get my React components to show up, and the only clue was this console message:

```
@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong.
```

I searched for this message and found lots of pages that weren't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I got React to work by adding this HTML to my `templates/base.html` Jinja template:

```html
<script type="module">
    import RefreshRuntime from 'http://localhost:3000/@react-refresh'
    RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
    window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
    window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
    window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
</script>
```

This can go right before or after the `<html>` opening tag, and is crucial for giving React access to the DOM. I found it at https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html.

After that flask-vite worked well for integrating React components into my Flask app.